# Mapping ElasticSearch GeoPoint Fields

Tags: ruby, search, geolocation, elasticsearch, tire

We store documents that look something like this:

```
{
    "id": "dQesbpxeQniUWXpsnjPQ",
    "title": "Golf in Hamburg, Altona",
    "user": "CtGjEaDxSrhPbf7W7NcH",
    "location": {
        "id": "Q6sZhRHdiS3mP2innbJ9",
        "name": "Hamburg, Altona",
        "lat": 53.55,
        "lon": 9.93333,
        "slug": "hamburg-altona"
    },
    "_type": "announcement"
}
```

We need the `announcement.location.slug` to be `not_analyzed` (it's a slug, after all)

However the mapping won't take, we have these settings:

```
Tire.index(@@index_name) do
  delete
  create(mappings: {
    announcement: {
      properties: {
        "id"       => { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' },
        "user"     => { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' },
        "location" => {
          type: 'geo_point',
          properties: {
            "slug" => { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' }
          }
        },
        "times"    => { type: 'string', analyzer: 'keyword'   },
        "sport" => {
          "properties" => {
            "slug" => { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  settings: {
    index: {
      number_of_shards: 1,
      number_of_replicas: 0
    }
  })
  refresh
end
```

**Note:** The same mapping in `curl` syntax also doesn't work, but is less readable for SO, so I'm posting the Ruby code.

It seems like `geo_point` is overriding all other mappings on that part of the document. [The documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html) seems to agree.

I'm sure there's a way to use the `lat_lon` option, but I can't find any documentation on how that might work. (I assume one maps the individual `lat` and `lon` fields with `lat_lon` settings)

It might also be possible, I had hoped to use [the `multi` field type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) but that doesn't seem to apply to whole sub-trees of the main document attributes.

How can I proceed without having to change my whole data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you have to change your model as geo_point is a full data type and you can not add properties (meta) in it.

Comment: We were able to change the `to_indexed_hash` method quite easily, and update the mapping very well, fortunately our test suite caught a bunch of small errors, all easy to fix. Thanks for the confirmation of my assumptions!